# fastai machine learning model predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

this is my simple model, that distinguish between 2 input categories.

```
from fastai.vision.all import *
dblock = DataBlock(blocks=(ImageBlock,CategoryBlock),
                  get_items = get_image_files,
                  splitter = RandomSplitter(),
                  get_y = parent_label,
                  item_tfms=Resize(256)
                  )
dls = dblock.dataloaders(path)
learn = cnn_learner(dls,resnet18, metrics = accuracy)
learn.fine_tune(1)
```

now, when i type:

```
learn.show_results()
```

I successfully get my results, the original labels and the predicted labels are matching, so I assuming that the model is working correctly.

but the problem is when I'm trying to feed my model with any specific image, to get the prediction from the model for this particular image, I've got a huge 200 lines error.

```
pil_img = Image.open('my_path_to_the_image.jpg') 
fastai_img = PILImage.create(pil_img)  # Convert to a fastai PILImage
```

when I'm loading the image, he is loaded correctly, and I can display him.

but then when I'm trying to predict:

```
learn.predict(pil_img)
```

I've got a huge error:

the upper part of the errror:

> "AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) Cell In[48], line 1
> ----> 1 learn.predict(pil_img)"

the lower part of the error:

> "File
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py:548,
> in Image.**getattr**(self, name)
> 541     warnings.warn(
> 542         "Image categories are deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 "
> 543         "(2023-07-01). Use is_animated instead.",
> 544         DeprecationWarning,
> 545         stacklevel=2,
> 546     )
> 547     return self._category
> --> 548 raise AttributeError(name)
>
> AttributeError: read"

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timely question. I (and many others) have run into the same issue over the past few weeks.

#### Background

It's not just you. This is a [known bug in fastai](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/issues/3880), evidently identified by students like yourself upon release of version `2.7.11` last month.

According to the issue above, [this PR implements a fix](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/pull/3884). Jeremy [merged it last week](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/commit/5684969a9561b61b9c93ff130c31399ebc2127a2), to be included in the next release.

#### Workaround

In the meantime, it *is* possible to pass images to `learn.predict` in v2.7.11, though you'll need to use techniques not shown in the book.

The `AttributeError` is thrown when `learn.predict` is passed a `PILImage`, so we can't currently use the result of calling `PILImage.create` as an argument to `learn.predict`.

The below all work for me on FastAI version `2.7.11`, running Python 3.10.1.

##### Using File Paths

Incidentally, 2.7.11 seems to able to accept a local file path directly:

```py
# This works for me
pred, pred_idx, probs = learn_inf.predict('path/to/file')
```

You should also be able to use `Image.open` directly, without invoking `PILImage.create`:

```py
test_file = 'path/to/file'
image = Image.open(test_file)
pred, pred_idx, probs = learn_inf.predict(image)
```

##### Using Byte Data

When you hit the Gradio/Hugging Face/etc. portion of the Book, you'll use widgets to create an upload buttons, allowing you to upload an image to pass to your model.

In this case, you don't have a file path to load as an `Image`. Instead, the widget will load the image's *byte* data into memory, thus `Image.open` will break:

```py
# Create Upload Widget -- Directly from Fastbook
btn_upload = widgets.FileUpload()
btn_upload

# RAISES ERROR 
image = Image.open(btn_upload.data[-1])
```

In this case, you need to convert `btn_upload.data[-1]` to an `_io.BytesIO` stream using [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o). The result can be passed to `learn.predict` as before:

```py
# Import io.BytesIO
from io import BytesIO

# Create Upload Widget -- Directly from Fastbook
btn_upload = widgets.FileUpload()
btn_upload

# Loads Image
image = Image.open(BytesIO(btn_upload.data[-1]))

# Predict
learn.predict(image)
```

##### Additional Bugs

There's a very good chance you'll get the below error at some point, if you're using your own images:

```py
# Lots of gross output...

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (4) must match the size of tensor b (3) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

This is usually due to your image containing Alpha in addition to RGB channels. You can bypass the error by eliminating the alpha channel via `Image`'s `convert` method:

```py
# Load image and throw out alpha channel
image = Image.open(BytesIO(btn_upload.data[-1])).convert('RGB')
```

Let us know if this helps. Good luck!